# How to translate "maximal ratio of improvement of the second objective function over deterioration of the first"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I'm looking for an appropriate translation of the following sentence, found in a paper on a bi-objective simplex algorithm:

> The algorithm iteratively generates entering variables which have a
>   maximal ratio of improvement of the second objective function over deterioration of the first.

My attempt so far:

> Der Algorithmus berechnet iterativ eintretende Variablen, die mit dem größten Verhältnis von Verbesserung bezüglich der zweiten Zielfunktion zur Verschlechterung bezüglich der ersten Zielfunktion korrespondieren.

Does this literal translation work? Or are there German idioms that can be used to make this passage sound more authentically German?

Comment: I modified the question to ask about the validity of a literal translation versus an idiomatic translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd split it into two sentences if that's possible (and if I understood your sentence right):

> Die Verbesserung der zweiten Zielfunktion führt (oft) zu einer relativen Verschlechterung der ersten Zielfunktion. Der Algorithmus generiert/bestimmt iterativ die(jenigen) Eingangsvariablen, die dieses Verhältnis zugunsten der zweiten Zielfunktion maximieren.
>
> The improvement of the second objective function (often) results in a relative deterioration of the first. The algorithm iteratively generates/determines the/those input variables that maximize this ratio to favour the second function.

Comment: The first sentence sounds really odd (because its trivially true) in the context of e.g. the simplex algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any German equivalent for "entering variables" (but maybe one does exist). I'll use "auszutauschende Variable", assuming you are talking about something similar to the simplex method.

> Der Algorithmus bestimmt der Reihe nach auszutauschende Variablen, die das Verhältnis der Verbesserung der zweiten Zielfunktion in Relation zur Verschlechterung der ersten Zielfunktion maximieren.

Comment: Perhaps _Eingangsvariablen_ (like _input variables_?)

Comment: @PerlDog: You know how the simplex algorithm works? These are *not* "input variables".

Comment: @dirkt: After some reading in German [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex-Verfahren), I assume, that there  *Schlupfvariable* is used, but never heard that before.

Comment: @guidot: The English word for "Schlupfvariable" is "slack variable".

Comment: @guidot: Nein, Schlupfvariablen dienen dazu, die Ungleichungen in Gleichungen zu überführen (wie in Wikipedia beschrieben). Entering und leaving variables sind diejenigen, die als Pivot gegen eine Basisvariable ausgetauscht werden. Es empfiehlt sich wirklich, Fachvokabular nur zu übersetzen, wenn man die Fachausdrücke auch kennt.